# Custom Validation for dynamically generated textboxes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The code for dynamically generated textboxes uisng *ngFor

```
<tr *ngFor="let computer in _Computers; let i = index;">
<td>{{computer.Name}}</td><td>{{computer.Optional}}</td>
<td> <input matInput [formControl] = "frmCtrl"  name="UnitofPrice" [(ngModel)]="computer[i]">
</td>
<td>{{computer.UnitofPrice}}</td>
```

Typescript code

```
public frmCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl('', this.customValidator());
customValidator() {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if ((!control.value)) {
        return { 'textRequired': true };
      }
      return null;
    };
 }
```

The above code works fine. That is whenever the textbox is empty, it is showing error. Suppose, I want to validate only the textboxes based on the "Optional" property of the computer list. Here, How to pass the computer Id or optional property to custom validator function? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize a form and formarray, besides, what you have now, is **one** single formcontrol for your whole array, so I cannot see how it works for your array.

Also, the validator you have written is basically a `required` validator, so you could use the inbuilt validator for that. So I suggest the following:

I have hardcoded `_Computers` array, I build the form, I loop the `_Computers` and add formcontrols to the formarray. Based on the `Optional` property I set `Validators.required` for the unit price only for those that the `Optional` value is `false`. Here I am pushing 2 formcontrols to each formgroup in the array, the `name` and the `unitOfPrice`, you can push any amount you want.

I make a getter for the formarray, just for easier access. All in all, code would look like this:

```
_Computers = [
  { Name: 'name1', Optional: true, UnitOfPrice: null },
  { Name: 'name2', Optional: false, UnitOfPrice: null },
];
myForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    computers: this.fb.array([]),
  });
  this._Computers.forEach((x: any) => {
    if (x.Optional) {
      this.computersArr.push(this.fb.group({
        name: [x.Name],
        unitOfPrice: [null]
      }));
    } else {
      this.computersArr.push(this.fb.group({
        name: [x.Name],
        unitOfPrice: [null, [Validators.required]]
      }));
    }
  });
}

get computersArr() {
  return (this.myForm.get('computers') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

I have been lazy and used `any` here, please type your data instead!

The template would then show the form, and we can display a message of required if it has such a validator:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="computers">
    <div *ngFor="let computer of computersArr; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <label>{{computer.get('name').value}}</label>
        <input formControlName="unitOfPrice" />
        <small *ngIf="computer.get('unitOfPrice').hasError('required')">Required!!</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Above is using `div`'s but you can easily replicate the same for a table.

Here is a **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rdbbcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** for your reference.